# Ruby on Rails, realtime calc

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

im learning RoR atm and im trying to code a calculator webapp.
The thing is: I want that the operations are gettin calculated in realtime.
So if i type in 2+2 the calc says 4 without that i pressed some "CALC NOW" button.

Can someone give me some hints how i could to that? Do i need to learn AJAX for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the calculations on the client side using JavaScript only. Or you can use JavaScript-driven automatic form submit or AJAX to send the input to the server and calculate with Ruby on Rails.

To calculate on the server side:

routes:

```
resources :calculators
```

CalculatorsController

```
def create
  @sum = eval(params[:data])
end
```

app/views/calculators/create.js.erb

```
document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = <%= @sum %>
```

app/views/calculators/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag calculators_path, :method => :post, :remote => true do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :data, nil, :onkeyup => "this.form.sub.click()" %> = <span id="sum"></span>
  <%= submit_tag "ok", :name => "sub" %>
<% end %>
```

now go to `/calculators` and enjoy

Comment: It´s about learning RoR (or just Ruby) so thats not very helpful.

Comment: so if you want to calculate on server side you need to learn something about ajax

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had something similar but i still dont know how i can calculate on the fly without pressing Enter for every calculation.

Comment: you should add `onchange` event - and this is still javascript :)

Comment: Ahh, so i need to add it to the create.js file? This javascript stuff just confuses me lol